# How to move route buttons in google maps in android?

Tags: android, maps, marker

I don't know how can I move the buttons of the route that google maps displays in the right bottom map when I select a marker.

I searched, but I didn't found any example.
Can you help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can disable this feature:
`getMap().getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);`

or pick up the keys higher:
`getMap().setPadding(0, 0, 0, banner.height);`